# WCF Service Library Request Too large

Tags: .net, wcf

I have tried every suggestion in every topic on "Request Too Large" for a WCF Service Library and none of them are working.  I have changed the binding, set configurations, and more and I'm just completely stumped.

I'm hoping someone can help me on this:

Here is my server side config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>
  <!--
    For a description of web.config changes see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235367.

    The following attributes can be set on the <httpRuntime> tag.
      <system.Web>
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />
      </system.Web>
  -->
  <system.web>
    <compilation strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.5.1"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
          <services>
         <service name="MyService.MyService">
         <endpoint name="webHttpBinding"
                   address=""
                   binding="webHttpBinding"
                   bindingConfiguration="webHttpBinding"
                   contract="MyService.IMyFunctions"/>
      </service>

      </services>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="webHttpBinding" scheme="http"/>
    </protocolMapping>
 <bindings>
    <webHttpBinding>
      <binding name="webHttpBinding" closeTimeout="00:10:00"
      openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00"
      maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
          maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      </binding>
    </webHttpBinding>
   </bindings>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <add name="UrlRoutingModule"
           type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, &#xD;&#xA;          System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, &#xD;&#xA;          Culture=neutral, &#xD;&#xA;          PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <add name="UrlRoutingHandler"
         preCondition="integratedMode"
         verb="*" path="UrlRouting.axd"
         type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler, &#xD;&#xA;         System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, &#xD;&#xA;         PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

And here is my app.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
      <bindings>
        <webHttpBinding>
          <binding name="webHttpBinding" closeTimeout="00:10:00"
          openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00"
          maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
          transferMode="Streamed">
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
              maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          </binding>
        </webHttpBinding>
      </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://blah/MyService.svc"
                binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webHttpBinding"
                contract="MyService.IMyFunctions" name="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="webhttp" />
        </client>
      <behaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
          <behavior name="webhttp">
            <webHttp/>
          </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
      </behaviors>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

everythign works except the request too large and i cannot for the life of my determine what is going wrong.  I have gone thru every request for help on this in stack exchange and nothing seems to make a difference.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is your request really too large? How many objects do you try to transfer or is it binary/character data?

Comment: Its larger than 64k.  The particular request is a JPG which I have fed into a stream of bytes.  The function works perfectly until it crosses the 64k boundary